# Python: initialise list of list of list of ... etc

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have written a function that creates an empty nested list of arbitrary depth. It has an outer function and an inner function, but I'm not quite sure if using an inner function is really necessary. Is there a way of refactoring or rewriting it without an inner function? Or is it even possible to use a for loop?

```
def nested_list(depth):
    def inner(my_list):
        if len(my_list) == 1: return[my_list[0]]
        return [inner(my_list[1:])]
    return inner([[] for x in range(depth)])
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going for shortest code possible, recursion can make it even shorter.

```
def nested_list(depth):
  return [nested_list(depth - 1)] if depth else []
```

An even cooler method that doesn't require a loop or recursion is with the `reduce()` function:

```
def nested_list(depth):
  reduce(lambda l, n: [l], xrange(depth), [])
```

For Python 3:

```
import functools
def nested_list(depth):
  functools.reduce(lambda l, n: [l], range(depth), [])
```

Comment: In python 3 `reduce` is moved to `functools.reduce`.

Comment: I find the recursive solution not only the shortest one but the clearest one!

Answer (score 2):

If you want for loops, You can use:

```
def nested_list(depth):
    x=[]
    if depth==0:
        return x
    for i in range(depth):
        x=[x]
    return x
```

Comment: You don't need the `if depth==0` part, the `for` loop iterates zero times in that case.